# Ubuntu 17.10 - Screencast always 0 bytes

Tags: 17.10, screencast

I read that there is a feature to save videos using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and I decided to try it:

- I pressed the combination
- Did some silly things to get recorded
- Pressed the combination once more
- I went to check out the webm file created

To my surprise, the video is 0 bytes big. How could this be? Do I have something misconfigured?

EDIT: To be clear, this problem affects only screencasting. Taking screenshots works without a problem.

Comment: Don't think it's the same issue, CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+R should work in a Wayland session.